# JProfiler startup error of Jetty application can't find libjprofilerti.so

Tags: java, jprofiler

I am trying to perform a remote profile session of Jetty.
I have downloaded, untar'd jprofiler_linux_7_0.tar.gz
I ran jpintegrate and produced the start_jetty_jprofiler.sh
Looked into that and snipped out the:
-agentpath:/RAID10/home/mbl/profiler/jprofiler7/bin/linux-x86/libjprofilerti.so=port=8849,nowait

and added that to my actual jetty startup script.

ran that modified script and I get the following error message:
Could not find agent library in absolute path: /RAID10/home/mbl/profiler/jprofiler7/bin/linux-x86/libjprofilerti.so

I'm wondering where I went wrong.
Thanks

Comment: @mbl Are you running a 64-bit JVM and using a 32-bit version of the agent library?

Comment: @user1005698: Have you check the library at that location?

Answer (score 3):

Probably you're trying to profile a 64-bit VM. In that case change `linux-x86` to `linux-x64`.

The error message in that case is indeed very misleading. The JVM should rather say something like "A 64-bit JVM cannot load a 32-bit library".

Answer (score 0):

uncheck the 64-bit vm option in jprofiler while creating the profiling settings. this should solve the issue

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem too. It resolved by copy linux-x64/ to linux-x86/ in the /jprofiler7/bin dir. Of course, please make sure to backup the linux-x86 first.